# Why do I get the "Not a managed type" error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My main project (A) contains the structure:
**x.y.z**

My project depends on a jar file (B) with **a.b.c** package structure

**Project B** contains the entity that I need in project A.

In **project A**, I specify the following.

```
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {"x.y.z", "a.b.c"},
    includeFilters = {
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, classes = {Indexed.class})
    })
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"x.y.z", "a.b.c"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer { ...
```

My entity in **Project B**:
a.b.c.models.MyEntity;

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(
    name = "my_entity"
)
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
public class MyEntity { ...
```

But every time I start, I get the same error *"Not a managed type: a.b.c.models.MyEntity"*.

I have tried different configurations, specify different paths, use import annotation, but nothing works.

```
@Configuration
@Import({MyEntity.class})
... Not Work ...
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"x.y.z.*", "a.b.c.*"})
... Not Work ...
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"x.y.z.models.*", "a.b.c.models*"})
... Not Work ...    
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {"x.y.z.*", "a.b.c.*"},
    includeFilters = {
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, classes = {Indexed.class})
    })
```

It's always the same mistake. But dependencies from Project A are loaded without problems.

I also have other projects C D E, which also depend on **jar project B**, it works fine in them with the same configuration.

Comment: can you please provide the stacktrace?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thank you for trying to help, but I found the reason. P.S. the stacktrace only printed the error inability to create a MyRepository, because MyEntity not a manage type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. The problem was this dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-indexer</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.21</version>
</dependency>
```

The beans in **project B** **(a.b.c package)** simply did not get into the **META-INF/spring.components** file.

You either need to remove this dependency, or generate your own **META-INF/spring.components** file for **project B**.